# Where does Android acquire the weather (temperature) that it displays on the main screen?

Tags: weather

I am building an app that will need several weather parameters. If they are already available somewhere internally, I would like to access them. If not, please identify the web service(s) that Android is using, if possible.

Specifically I am seeking temperature, pressure, and relative humidity.

Thank you.

Comment: Weather apps are manufacturer specific. Hence your question can't be answered as it it unclear of which weather app you are talking about. In any way there are dozen of weather data provider. Usually those provider require a registration and some times you have to pay for the data. The only alternative are community based weather data provider such as wunderground.com or openweathermap.org.

Comment: Android (AOSP) doesn't show temperature, apps do. So it's up to the developers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15425283/9165920

Comment: @Robert My Pixel 2XL displays the outdoor temperature on the factory locked screen as well as the main unlocked screen, so that is why I attribute that to the OS rather than an app.

Comment: @Kirk Pixel devices don't run Android (AOSP). Hence it has been added by Google specific for the device. Only Android One devices run a nearly plain Android. In any way you are usually not allowed to use the same API. If you want to know where it gets the data redirect the traffic through a decrypting HTTP(S) proxy and prepare your device to accept the proxy certificate.

Comment: Google (including Nexus and Pixel devices) uses Weather.com. It's the same as querying "weather" on Google search (there's "More on weather.com" on the bottom).